# NextJs 13 - Getting 404 on every route change with App + Page router, due to catch-all route. Doesn't happen on Production Build

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I had my project on Pages router, but recently updated to NextJs 13 with App router. Now using **Pages router along with App router**.

Since then, I am getting **404 when navigating to any route**. Then I have to refresh it once and it works fine. Repeat.

This **doesn't happen on Production deployment**.

I have found the culprit and its happening because of the below **catch-all segment**.

`pages/[...project].tsx`

If I change it to a normal route like `project.tsx`, the 404 issue doesn't happen and routing works properly.

Need help in identifying how to fix these 404 on every navigation.
Also need to understand **why it isn't happening in Production deployment**.